# method is started when launched

Tags: java, user-interface, methods

So, I have a gameOver() method that should when oval goes out of bounds abort game but, as soon as I start the game it runs the gameOver method. I've been looking over it for a while trying different things. I think what stood out to me is removing the abort sequence the game runs mostly as it should after, popup is closed and that if I replace game.gameOver(); with ya = -1 the ball bounces off the wall.

gaveOver()

```
public void gameOver(){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over", "Game Over", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    System.exit(ABORT);
}
```

move()

```
package com.edu4java.minitennis1;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
 import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Ball {
private static final int DIAMETER = 30;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int xa = 1; // Represent the speed in which the ball is moving
int ya = 1; // Represent the speed in which the ball is moving
private Game game;

public Ball(Game game){
    this.game=game;
}

/*
 * If xa=1, the ball moves to the right, one pixel every round of the Game Loop,
 * if xa=-1, the ball moves to the left. 
 * If ya=1 moves the ball down and 
 * If ya=-1 moves the ball up.
 */

void move(){
    if (x + xa < 0) // Makes left bounds
        xa = 3; // Moves the ball right
    if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - DIAMETER) // Makes right bounds
        xa = -3; // Moves the ball left
    if(y + ya < 0) // Makes top bounds
        ya = 3; // Moves ball down

    if(y + ya > game.getHeight() - DIAMETER) // Makes bottom bounds
        game.gameOver();

    if (collision()){ // Makes collision with Racquet
        ya = -3;
        y = game.racquet.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
    }
    x = x + xa;
    y = y + ya;
}

private boolean collision(){
    return game.racquet.getBounds().intersects(getBoundsBall());
}

public void paint(Graphics2D g){
    g.fillOval(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
}

public Rectangle getBoundsBall(){
    return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
}

}
```

The problems has been resolved I just went back and rewrote the move() method and replaced it with

```
void move(){
     if(x + xa < 0)// Makes left bounds
         xa = 1;// Moves the ball right
     if(x + xa == game.getWidth() - DIAMETER)// Makes right bounds
         xa = -1;// Moves the ball left
     if (y + ya < 0)// Makes top bounds
         ya = 1;// Moves ball down
     if(y + ya == game.getHeight() - DIAMETER){ // Makes bottom bounds
        ya = 0;// Moves ball up
        xa = 0;
        game.gameOver();
     }
```

Sometimes all you need to do is go back.

Comment: where is the code that calls gameOver()?

Comment: Can't see gameOver() called here.

Comment: `if(y + ya > game.getHeight() - DIAMETER) game.gameOver();` for those who were looking. Wasnt that hard to find

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your question yourself I think. Assuming there are no further calls to your gameOver() method than the one that's in your move() method, than gameOver is called from this if block:

```
if(y + ya > game.getHeight() - DIAMETER)
    game.gameOver();
```

Which means that `(y + ya)` is greater than `(game.getHeight() - DIAMETER)`. Since I don't know what your variables are supposed to be I can only guess that there might be a problem with your initial values,etc.

Try stepping through your program with a debugger and it will be much easier to see the problem and understand what's going on.

Comment: here is the entire ball class. Also, yes this is the only call the gameOver() but, that's why I am confused lol. it goes directly to gameOver() while if I changed gameOver() to ya = -1; then, it plays like it should exception to being no game over.

Comment: Check out the values on the left side of your if (y and ya) and on the right side of your if (game.getHeight() and DIAMETER). If you do not have a debugger simply print them to System.out like System.out.println(y);...
Maybe game.getHeight() does not do what it's supposed to do...